# How can I get a OPDS catalog listing of pdf's in a collection

Tags: dspace

Can someone say if it is currently possible to get a OPDS catalog listing of ebooks that I have stored in a collection. I want to use an Android ereader app to browse then download selected pdf's or epub bitstreams to a tablet.

Answer (score 0):

OPDS catalog feeds are currently **not** offered as a standard feature of DSpace.

The [OPDS primer](http://www.feedbooks.com/api/primer) makes it clear that it has quite a few things in common with an atom feed.

If you would want to customize this in DSpace, you could modify [SyndicationFeed.java](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-api/src/main/java/org/dspace/app/util/SyndicationFeed.java).

Comment: If I modify the SyndicationFeed code how would I install this copy in the dspace.cfg to get it activated.

Comment: Also in looking at the configuration for RSS feeds in dspace.cfg and it seems to only get called for new and updated items. I would want the OPDS catalog listing to be available for a particular url. Would it not be better for me to get the listing via the dspace REST API.